# How to create a file in a python script without storing it in a local directory and save it in a different container on azure blob storage?

Tags: python, azure, deployment, azure-blob-storage

Because I want to deploy this code as an azure container instance, I don't want to read a file from a local path on my computer. Basically, I am retrieving a file from a container in blob storage in Azure and then saving it in a different container. There would be some processing that changes the file from the blob storage and uploads the processed file into a different container. In my code, for simplicity I am uploading the file as it is without processing it and changing the file. So far I have managed to read a file from blob storage and make a local file out of it and upload the local file to a different container on blob storage but I don't want to create a local file. I want to process the file from blob storage and directly upload it to a different container without storing it in a local path. Can someone please help me figure it out. I have the following code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import json

class FileProcessing:

    def __init__(self):
        self.file_access()

    def file_access(self):
        filename = "data_map.json"

        container_name="filestorage"
        constr = ""

        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(constr)
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)
        streamdownloader = blob_client.download_blob()

        fileReader = json.loads(streamdownloader.readall())

        #Here it stores it in a local directory on my computer; I want it saved on Azure directly
        #For simplicity I am not making any changes to the file yet
        with open('json_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(fileReader, outfile)

        container_name2="filedeposit"

        container_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(constr, container_name2)
        print("Uploading files to blob storage")

        blob_client= container_client.get_blob_client("json_data.json") 
        with open(r"C:\Users\python-test\json_data.json", "rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)
            print("file uploaded")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FileProcessing()
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need to write the data to the file. You can simply convert the JSON data into a string and then upload it. Something like (untested code though):

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import json

class FileProcessing:

    def __init__(self):
        self.file_access()

    def file_access(self):
        filename = "data_map.json"

        container_name="filestorage"
        constr = ""

        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(constr)
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)
        streamdownloader = blob_client.download_blob()

        fileReader = json.loads(streamdownloader.readall())
        #Read the data into string
        data = json.dumps(fileReader)

        container_name2="filedeposit"

        container_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(constr, container_name2)
        print("Uploading files to blob storage")

        blob_client= container_client.get_blob_client("json_data.json") 
        blob_client.upload_blob(data)
        print("file uploaded")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FileProcessing()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what to remove from the code I have to make it work? Right now you just added the string and let the rest of the code stay as it is!

Comment: I just removed the code where you’re saving the file locally. Everything else remains the same.

Comment: Sorry, found one issue in my code. Please see the updated answer. I also removed the code where you are reading data from local file just before uploading.

Comment: Instead of storing it as a string is there any way to make a file that's saved directly to blob storage? I have to work on decrypting pdf files and saving the decrypted pdf file in blob storage? And also saving files as csv. Is that possible?

Comment: String was just an example (as I thought you’re working with JSON files). You can work with streams in a similar way (not very proficient in Python thus won’t be able to provide code for that ). HTH.